# How to User not operator In MongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb

I have been troubled By this question much time. There has a collection which has a phone_num column,
how can I query the document except the column value is not 12563254154

Answer (score 2):

Use the $ne operator
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24ne
So for example

db.things.find( { phone_num  : { $ne : 12563254154 } } );

Comment: Thank You!  I solve this question like this:
 List<Map> results = mongoTemplate.find(
       Query.query(Criteria.where("mobile_num").ne("12563254154").in("13592422335")), 
                                     Map.class, BlackListMobile);